# Management after Software Engineering undergraduate degree or separate management masters degree?

Tags: career-path, software, engineering, management

I am currently an undergraduate student studying BEng (Hons) Software Engineering at University of Greenwich. I want to do masters but I am not sure what to do. I am a very talented software architect and programmer. I have two years worth of industrial experience (1 year at IBM and 1 year at NHS).

I am interested in technical side of things in industry which is why I have been considering to do MEng Software Engineering. However, in future I want to move into management side of things while staying technical at the same time. My ambition is to become a CTO. What would you advise?

Would you advise me to do MEng Software Engineering and then MBA? Or shall I do MBA straight away after my software engineering undergraduate degree?

Thanks a bunch in advance. 
Manthan Dave

Answer (score 4):

IMO, MEng Software Engineering.

You need to stay on technical side. Do MBA after you have more years of industrial experience if you think you need to.

The CEO depends on CTO for technical decision. CTO needs to have a lot technical knowledge. For example, you need to be able to tell one software architecture is better than the other.

Comment: Absolutely right. Get the tech down first, then get the experience, then focus on the business side.

Comment: Is there anything else that I can do to boost my career? Any certifications that can give me a jump start? I have been looking at TOGAF but I am not sure if that is the right direction.

Comment: @ManthanDave This is Academia SE. Certifications question is out of scope.